# Is the something like SVN for operating systems?

Tags: linux, laptop, usb, repository

the title to this question maybe misleading since i dont know if its something already out there

my question is lets say we had a Linux machine and and u clone it onto a USB flash so that you can use it on other computers and if make any changes you can just plug your USB back an update the machine, something along the lines of git-hub or SVN but for an operating system?

Comment: Virtual Machines such as [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org) and [VMWare](http://www.vmware.com/) allow you to take snapshots of the hard drive at different points in time and then revert back to those snapshots.

Comment: could i take a snapshot of a distro on a USB then do something along the lines of an update on the desktop machine?

Comment: Microsoft is working on a new file system for version control, but I believe it's based on git, not svn

Comment: @William there are hundreds of tools that can convert a physical machine to a virtual image and vice versa (I.e VM to physical machine )

Comment: yeah but wouldn't that mean that the system would be replaced?

Comment: @Ramhound Do you have a source for that? Just interested in reading more about it.

Comment: @AndreTerra Just search for **GVFS**